# Get an Object from Firebase Firestore in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I alredy searched here in the forum but i didn't find nothing like that. I want to get an Object from Firebase Firestore, but I can't manipulate the object that I am receiving. How can I separate the `imageLink` from the `imageTitle`?

The database structure is:
[image: Database Structure]

The code I am using is:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("image").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
                val imageData = documentSnapshot.documents[0].data?.getValue("imageData")
            }
```

But, when I do that, I receive something like that:
[image: Data that I'm receiving]

How can I get the `imageLink` from the `imageTitle` separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try casting `imageData` as a `Map` as shown below:

```
db.collection("images").limit(1).get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
    val imageData =
        querySnapshot.documents[0].data!!.getValue("imageData")?.let { it as Map<*, *> }

    val imageLink = imageData?.get("imageLink")
    val imageTitle = imageData?.get("imageTitle")

    Log.d("MainActivity", "imageLink: $imageLink")
    Log.d("MainActivity", "imageTitle: $imageTitle")
}
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) for `let` for more information.

---

You are calling `get()` on a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) that will fetch all documents from the collection (if you add any). If you only want to fetch 1st document from the collection, you can add [`limit(1)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) that'll save any additional charges.